# How to Optimize Nested Loops for Tensor Operations in NumPy/TensorFlow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, optimization, vectorization

I am working on a machine learning problem involving a Monte Carlo simulation for a classification task. My current implementation involves generating synthetic class labels based on multinomial distributions and computing a specific tensor product between input features and generated labels. The goal is to estimate a regularization threshold for an ANN classification model. However, the nested loop for calculating a four-dimensional array xy seems to be a bottleneck, and I'm looking for ways to optimize this using vectorization or any other efficient approach.

Current Implementation:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def lamb(xsample, hat_p_training, nSample=100000, miniBatchSize=500, alpha=0.05, option='quantile'):
    if np.mod(nSample,miniBatchSize) == 0:
        offset = 0
    else: 
        offset = 1
        
    n, p1 = xsample.shape
    number_class = len(hat_p_training)

    fullList = np.zeros((miniBatchSize*(nSample//miniBatchSize+offset),))

    for index in range(nSample//miniBatchSize+offset):
        ySample = np.random.multinomial(1, hat_p_training, size=(n, 1, miniBatchSize))
        y_mean = np.mean(ySample, axis=0)

        xy = np.zeros(shape=(n, p1, miniBatchSize, number_class))
        for index_n in np.arange(n):
            xy[index_n, :, :, :] = np.outer(xsample[index_n, :], (y_mean-ySample)[index_n, :, :]).reshape((p1, miniBatchSize, number_class))
        
        xymax = np.amax(tf.reduce_sum(np.abs(tf.reduce_sum(xy, axis=0).numpy()), axis=2).numpy(), axis=0)

    # Further processing...
```

Specific Question:

- How can I optimize the calculation of xy, currently implemented with a for-loop and reshaping operations, possibly using vectorization techniques in NumPy or TensorFlow? The goal is to eliminate or reduce the for-loop for efficiency.
- Is there a more efficient way to perform these tensor operations that could leverage the capabilities of TensorFlow or NumPy for better performance?

Context:

- xsample is a 2D NumPy array of shape (n, p1), representing input features.
- hat_p_training is a 1D array representing the estimated class probabilities.
- The code generates ySample, a synthetic label set based on hat_p_training, and computes xy, a tensor representing the product between transposed xsample and the difference y_mean-ySample.
- The ultimate goal is to find the maximum value across certain dimensions of xy for further processing.

I appreciate any insights or suggestions for optimizing this part of my code. Thank you!

Comment: That inner `index_n` can be reworked as a broadcasted multiply.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop using `outer` can be replaced with a single broadcasted multiply.

Making a sample calculation:

```
In [42]: n, p1, miniBatchSize, number_class = 5,4,3,2
    ...: x = np.arange(n*p1).reshape(n,p1)
    ...: y  = np.arange(n*miniBatchSize*number_class).reshape(n,miniBatchSize,number_class)
    ...: xy = np.zeros(shape=(n, p1, miniBatchSize, number_class))
    ...: for index_n in np.arange(n):
    ...:     xy[index_n, :, :, :] = np.outer(x[index_n, :], y[index_n, :, :]).reshape((p1, miniBatchSize, number_class))
    ...:     

In [43]: xy.shape
Out[43]: (5, 4, 3, 2)
```

And the broadcasted equivalent:

```
In [44]: xy1 = x[:,:,None,None] * y[:,None,:,:]

In [45]: xy1.shape
Out[45]: (5, 4, 3, 2)
In [46]: np.allclose(xy, xy1)
Out[46]: True
```

Depending on the size of `n` that could save time, and may make it easier to 'vectorize' the outer loop as well.  I haven't tried to understand or rewrite that part.

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize all with the following code:

```py
def lambda_qut_sann_classification_vec(xsample, hat_p_training, nSample=50000, miniBatchSize=500, y=0):
    if np.mod(nSample, miniBatchSize) == 0:
        offset = 0
    else:
        offset = 1

    n, p1 = xsample.shape
    number_class = len(hat_p_training)

    n_samples = nSample // miniBatchSize + offset
    # ySample = np.random.RandomState(0).multinomial(n_samples, hat_p_training, size=(n_samples, n, 1, miniBatchSize))
    ySample = y
    ySample = tf.convert_to_tensor(ySample)
    yMean = tf.reduce_mean(ySample, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    y = yMean - ySample
    y = tf.reshape(y, (y.shape[0], y.shape[1], -1))
    fullList = tf.einsum('xy,axb->axyb', xsample, y) #  this does the outer multiplication on the axes. 

    fullList = tf.reshape(fullList, (n_samples, n, p1, miniBatchSize, number_class))
    fullList = tf.reduce_sum(fullList, axis=1)
    fullList = tf.math.abs(fullList)
    fullList = tf.reduce_sum(fullList, axis=3)
    fullList = tf.reduce_max(fullList, axis=1)
    return tf.reshape(fullList, -1)
```

I changed the `ySample` to a parameter to give the same multinomial numbers to multiple functions for testing. You can just use the commented out line inside the function. I didn't find an equal TensorFlow function in the basic TF package, only in the [TensorFlow probability package](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Multinomial).

The `.einsum` does the vectorized job of `.outer`. `einsum` is very fast, but also very cryptic to read. Look at a few examples on the [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to get a grasp of it. Essentially, you give the shape of input and output as a string, and the same letters mean the same size in that dimension (`x` in the string is 10 in both xsample and y, `y` is 50).

Beware that numpy's default for float is `float64`, while TF's default is `float32`, leading to decreased numerical stability but improved performance, especially on GPU.
Unfortunately, I encountered numerical instability in the first sum:

> fullList = tf.reduce_sum(fullList, axis=1)

I swapped every tf function for a numpy function (e.g. `tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=1)` -> `np.sum(x, axis=1)`), and from this point on I got different values for tf and np, when `nSample` was 100_000 or bigger. It was stable with e.g. 50_000. It's really strange. You can still use the code with numpy functions. For me, it went from 16.6s to 4.2s for numpy, and 0.449s for TF with a GPU.

---

Edit: To compare it with your implementation, I added the `y` parameter to both functions, and in your implemetatio changed the line

```
for index in range(nSample // miniBatchSize + offset):
    ySample = np.random.multinomial(1, hat_p_training, size=(n, 1, miniBatchSize))  # this one
```

to

```
for index in range(nSample // miniBatchSize + offset):
    ySample = y[index]  # this one
```

Outside of both functions, I used

```
x = np.random.rand(10, 50)
hat_p_training = np.random.rand(50)
hat_p_training = hat_p_training/sum(hat_p_training)  # normalizing
nSample = 90_000
miniBatchSize = 500
n, p1 = x.shape
n_samples = nSample // miniBatchSize
y = np.random.RandomState().multinomial(
    n_samples, hat_p_training, size=(n_samples, n, 1, miniBatchSize)
    )
res = lambda_qut_sann_classification(x, hat_p_training, nSample=nSample, y=y)  # your function
res2 = res = lambda_qut_sann_classification_vec(x, hat_p_training, nSample=nSample, y=y)  # the vectorized version
```

to generate all neccessary input variables once, and to give them to both functions, that both have the same variables to start calculating. If you don't do that, `np.random.multinomial` will output different numbers for the functions, and this will lead to different results.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your version of the code for the lambda_qut_sann_classification function. I've tested it alongside the original version I have, and I noticed that the results between the two versions do not match. After carefully reviewing both implementations, I believe the discrepancy stems from the differences in how ySample is generated and subsequently processed to calculate the mean (yMean in the original version and yMean_tf in your version). Did you got same results? How?

Comment: I see there is a typo in the code. `yMean_tf` should be `yMean` in my code, because `yMean` is used in the next line. Otherwise, the difference for `ySample` in my code and your code is that I draw all samples at once, and you draw them 200x in the loop. Please beware that it draws random samples, so you have to use the same drawn numbers for `ySample` in both implementations. Thats why I added the `y` parameter, to give both functions the same drawn numbers.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer, to show how I generated the data outside of the functions. If you only use one function, you don't have to do that, but if you want to compare the computations, and you deal with random number generation, you either have to use a seed, if the shape is the same (it is not here, because you generate it in the for loop), or generate the same numbers for both functions one time.